# Android-Checking current device time in background

Tags: android, android-service

How to check the current device time in background at regular intervals(say every 1 hour) even after the app is closed using startService() method?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a service, depending on what you want to do with the time you get.

As a general rule, to do something at regular intervals you can use `AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating()` (or `setRepeeating()` if you really need a perfect periodicity). Use the `PendingIntent` of this method to start whatever (BroadcastReceiver, Activity, Service...) when the alarm is triggered.

Comment: I want to retrieve dates from database and check them against the date that I obtain at regular intervals.